# Extracting function from contour plot

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I have made a contour plot via `Minitab` and got an image like this one:

[image: contour plot]

With

- $z$ being the enthalpy $[BTU/lb]$
- $x$ being the temperature $[°F]$
- $y$ being the concentration [%]

How can I mathematically access its function $z = f(x,y)$ from just the data behind the picture?
Is there a possibility to get $z = f(x,y)$ from this via programming/software?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will not be able to recover the whole function, because there just isn't enough data. However, you can trace the contours where the value is known (for example: the boundary between dark blue and blue is where $f(x,y)=-100$), and then do some 2d (polynomial) interpolation (or fitting if you know the expression of $f$).

Comment: This site is for Q&A about the software application Mathematica and the Wolfram Language. Your question does not appear appropriate for this site.

Comment: If your question is about Mathematica software, please add the code that you have tried and describe any difficulties you have encountered.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the time to answer this completely, but this should get you started. First, import the image:

```
Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvVL1.png"]
```

Next, use the GUI crop tool to cut out the plot and assign it to a variable:

```
img = <...>
```

[image]

Detect the edges:

```
edges = EdgeDetect @ img
```

Separate the edges into components:

```
components = MorphologicalComponents[edges];
Counts[Flatten@components] (* see how many components there are *)
```

You'll need to define a function that maps the component numbers to the right contour values:

```
f[comp_] := ...
```

Next, create the interpolation function from the component data. In this case, there are 8 components, hence `Range[8]`:

```
int = Interpolation[
  Catenate[(Function[el, {el, f[#]}] /@ 
       Position[components, #, {2}]) & /@ Range[8]]
  ]
```

Plot the result:

```
Plot3D[int[x, y], {x, 1, 283}, {y, 1, 389}]
```

I chose `f[x_] := x` and got this:

[image]

You'll also need to map the image xy-coordinates to the actual coordinates to finish this.

Comment: Thanks for your time!